# Event tracking and virtual pageviews are not tracked in Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, pageviews, event-tracking

I'm trying to track how visitors interact with the price calculator that i placed on my website.

I've tried placing events and virtual pageviews in different places and events (onClick, onMouseDown, onMouseOver, in href attribute, onChange in the input tag). No matter what i do - no events or virtual pageviews are tracked, though i can see the __utm.gif requests for everything i want to track in FireBug, but nothing in GA reports.

Here's the calculator i'm [tracking](http://www.udalder.ru/udalenie_derevev) (it's in Russian, the event i'm trying to track is the big orange button).

Comment: And there's no filters applied, all other data is gathered properly. And i've tried asking in GA user forum, it seems to be dead, the only responce in month i got was from a person who has the same problem.

Comment: So in your pages reports, you see hits to the actual page this calculator is on "/udalenie_derevev", but no hits to the virtual pages? I see a _trackPageview() call passing "/virtual/trees/calculate" on various onmouseover,onchange, and onclicks, and at face value I see no reason you shouldn't be seeing "/virtual/trees/calculate" show up in your pages report.  But I do not see any event tracking on your page.

Comment: Also, how long ago did you implement this and are trying to see data? Data can take up to 24 hours to show up in GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I do see a _trackPageview() call passing "/virtual/trees/calculate" on various onmouseover,onchange, and onclicks, and at face value I see no reason you shouldn't be seeing "/virtual/trees/calculate" show up in your pages report, but google officially states that it takes up to 24 hours to see data.

Second, I do not see any event tracking on your page. I do not see any code for it, nor do I see any GA calls showing it from random interactions on your page.  If it is there, you will need to give detail about where it is and how it is coded.

Third, do you see the page view for the actual page? Which account/profile are you looking at? Because when I first load the page, I see two separate hits to GA happening, the first to account/profile # "UA-25026876-1" (which is from your on-page code) and the second to account/profile # "UA-20200270-1" (which is happening from a counter.js script include), and the second one is where your virtual page views are going to.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've replaces events with virtual pageviews in case they would work, but they didn't. This counter JS file had another GA tracking script. Looks like the previous webmaster for some reason placed 2 tracking scripts. I saw the event are sent, but i didn't catch they were sent to another account, you're my savior man.